# Removing model names in modelsummary

Tags: r, modelsummary

I wonder is it possible to remove model names entirely (and delete the row in the table). I tried setting them to NULL but that does not seem to work.

```
library(modelsummary)
x<-rnorm(5)
y<-rnorm(5)

models<-list(lm(y~x),lm(y~x))
names(models)<-NULL

#This still produces models with names
modelsummary(models)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option may be to set the names to blank (`""`)

```
names(models) <- rep("", length(models))
modelsummary(models)
```

-output

[image]

---

Deleting row - if it is coefficient, use `coef_omit

```
modelsummary(models, coef_omit = "x")
```

[image]

and if there are other parameters to be removed, can also use a regex in `gof_omit`

```
modelsummary(models, gof_omit = "AIC|BIC")
```

[image]

Comment: this is an excellent answer. But not exactly what I want, I really want to remove it physically, because after I do: ```add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Probability of Exit" = 4),line = FALSE) %>%``` and if I do not remove it, there is an empty space.

Comment: @Vitalijs wouldn't this be the names of the models, i.e. `setNames(models, ...)` before you apply `modelsummary`

Answer (score 0):

In the development version of `modelsummary` (version >0.9.4), all the extra arguments that you pass to `modelsummary` will be pushed through the ellipsis (`...`) automatically to `kableExtra::kbl()`. This means that you can use the `col.names=NULL` argument to get this:

```
library(remotes)
install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")

library(modelsummary)

mod <- list(
    lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars),
    lm(mpg ~ hp + drat, mtcars)
)

modelsummary(mod, col.names = NULL)
```

[image]